# Active navigation based on URL

Tags: jquery, html, css

My navigation menu looks like this

```
<div id="menu-div">
<ul>
<li><a href="localhost/admin/">Admin</a></li>
<li><a href="localhost/admin/page/">Pages</a></li>
<li><a href="localhost/admin/image/">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="localhost/admin/account/">Accounts</a></li>
<li><a href="localhost/admin/role">Roles</a></li>
<li><a href="localhost/admin/theme">Layout</a></li>
<li><a href="localhost/admin/backup">Backup</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to add an active class to the navigation links based on the URL. I tried the following jQuery function

```
$(function () {
   $('#menu-div a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] +    '"]').addClass('active');
        });
```

This function sets all the links to active instead of just the current one. There must be something wrong with the jQuery function. I'm not that good with it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use location.pathname with the jQuery endswith selector `[ attr $=""]`, which you can use to search a string for a substring. in this case, you're attempting to find the path specified . this is better than contains which could match similar paths like

/admin
/admin/foobar
/foobar/admin

would all match /admin

**BUT WAIT**

This solution is far too simple. we need to make sure path is an exact match of the href provided!

```
$(function () {
    (function(){   
       var path = location.pathname;
        $('#menu-div * a[href$="'+ path+'"]').each(function(index,element){
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            if(href.indexOf('http://') !== -1){
                var exact = href.substring(7,href.length).split('/');
            }else{
                var exact = href.split('/');
            }
            exact[0] = '';//get rid of the host
            exact = exact.join('/');
            if(path == exact){
                $(this).addClass('active'); 
            }
        });
    })();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axawbmt9/25/) (please note, you will have to click run since jsfiddle.net uses javascript to alias the actual pathname.

Comment: @BidhanA Please standby, i am going to improve the code. it can erroneously match additional paths.

Comment: @BidhanA updated with a more correct answer that should guard against path's ending in similar names, as well as href's that are relative ie `/path/to/page` with out http and host name.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery onLoad:

```
function() {
var whereAmI = window.location.pathname;
  switch(whereAmI){
    case "www.yourwebsite.com":
      /*do what you want*/
      break;
}    
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full path that you are working with so I'll make one up for an example. Let's say your path is:

```
file:///Users/yourname/Desktop/test.html
```

When you call:

```
location.pathname.split("/")
```

you get an array that looks like this:

```
["", "Users", "yourname", "Desktop", "test.html"]
```

Then when you call `[1]` on that array you get the second result (index starts at 0) which in this case is:

```
Users
```

Which is not what you want. You're looking for a path like this: `localhost/admin/`. So depending on what your path actually is, you might be looking for:

```
window.location.pathname
```

or the whole path minus the protocol:

```
window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to active the same path, when you click other link of this path,

```
path= "/First" =>>> path for First will active.
path= "/First/Second" path for First will active too.



 $(document).ready(function () {
            var path = window.location.pathname;
            if (path != "/") {
                $("#menuitems li a[href*='" + path + "']").addClass("active");
                var arr = path.split('/');
                if (arr.length > 2) {
                    var pathtoactive = "/" + arr[1];
                    $("#menuitems li a[href*='" + pathtoactive + "']").addClass("active");
                }
            }
        });
```